# Prevent Plus from threading InterpolatingFunction

Tags: evaluation, interpolation

For an `InterpolatingFunction` $y:\ \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$, `Plus` is unaware of this, so when I do any modifications to it in an unevaluated form, it breaks the result

```
y = Interpolation[Table[{i, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2]}, {i, 1, 10}]];
y[t]
y[t] + {1, 2}

(* InterpolatingFunction[{{1.,10.}},<>][t]`
{1+InterpolatingFunction[{{1.,10.}},<>][t],2+InterpolatingFunction[{{1.,10.}},<>][t]} *)
```

I ran into it doing things like:

```
y = Interpolation[Table[{i, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2]}, {i, 1, 10}]];
f[t_] := Piecewise[{{ {1, 2} + y[t], t < 5}}];
df[t_] := Evaluate[D[f[t], t]]
df[t]
df[3]
```

And I can't figure out how to prevent expressions like `{1,2} + y[t]` from being evaluated while still being able to differentiate them. If `Plus` just realized that `y[t]` is $\mathbb{R}^2$ valued, I think that would simplify everything for me. Is there some way to set this property?

Comment: I suppose `y[t_] = {Interpolation[Table[{i, RandomReal[{0, 1}]}, {i, 1, 10}]][t], Interpolation[Table[{i, RandomReal[{0, 1}]}, {i, 1, 10}]][t]}` is not what you're looking for?

Comment: Started rewriting my code to split everything up like that, but was hoping for some Hold magic :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` package one can implement the threading explicitly.

```
y = Interpolation[Table[{i, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2]}, {i, 1, 10}]];

<< DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`

yy = Interpolation[
  MapThread[
   List, {InterpolatingFunctionGrid[y], {1, 2} + # & /@ 
     InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[y]}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 
   First[InterpolatingFunctionInterpolationOrder[y]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Trying to override Plus
`Unprotect[Plus];
Plus[c_List, f_InterpolatingFunction] := 
  Interpolation[
   MapThread[
    List, {InterpolatingFunctionGrid[f], 
     c + # & /@ InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[f]}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 
    First[InterpolatingFunctionInterpolationOrder[f]]];`

But I think I have to hunt the documentation a bit to see how to do it properly

Comment: (Of course, if you're aware of the direct way to access those properties (e.g. `y["Grid"]` and `y["ValuesOnGrid"]`), you don't need to load the package...)

Comment: @J.M. ...and there's one of those features I didn't know about.  What other "properties" of `InterpolatingFunction` are there?

Comment: It seems the answer to my question is: "Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "Domain", "Evaluate", "Grid", "InterpolationOrder", "MethodInformation", "Methods", "Properties",
"ValuesOnGrid"

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, for reference, `y["Methods"]` will return that list of properties supported by an `InterpolatingFunction[]`.