# Apply UpValues before Listability

Tags: function-construction

I'm trying to modify `Plus` but am running into trouble with it being `Listable`:

```
ClearAll[f, g, h]
Attributes[f] = {Listable};
h /: f[x_h, l_List] := 0
h /: g[x_h, l_List] := 0
f[h[1], {1, 1}]   (* {f[h[1], 1], f[h[1], 1]}, not OK I want 0 *)
g[h[1], {1,1}]    (* 0 as expected *)
```

How can I make the UpValue (or equivalent) have higher priority than the listability?

**EDIT:**
I ended up wanting to do [this again](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14465/prevent-plus-from-threading-interpolatingfunction) and figured I'd fix the `Plus` properly.
Here it is working using Sashas answer and Mr.Wizards `$Pre` method:

```
    $Pre =.
ClearAll[myPlus]; Attributes[myPlus] = {Orderless};
Unprotect[InterpolatingFunction]; UpValues[InterpolatingFunction] = {};
InterpolatingFunction /: 
 myPlus[y_InterpolatingFunction[t_Symbol], l_List] := 
 Interpolation[
   MapThread[List, {y["Grid"], l + # & /@ y["ValuesOnGrid"]}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> First[y["InterpolationOrder"]]][t]
myPlus[other__] := +other
$Pre = Function[x, Unevaluated@x /. Plus -> myPlus, HoldAllComplete];
    Protect[InterpolatingFunction];

    y = Interpolation[Table[{i, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2]}, {i, 1, 10}]];
    ParametricPlot[{y[t], y[t] - {1, 1}}, {t, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: You can't do that, or I'll be very surprised. Change your design somehow. It's hard to help in that without knowing a little bit about the bigger picture. Perhaps for your case adding the "listability" as `e:f[_, l_List]:=Thread@Unevaluated@e` or something similar, but that depends on the case at hand

Comment: Oh, `f` is `Plus`, my bad.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Not possible (I even tried with `$Pre` and `$Post` to fool the evaluator, but you cannot do that). Just program `Listable like f[x_, l_List] := Thread[f, {x, l}];` and all is good.

Comment: @Rojo Updated with bigger picture

Comment: I think this is one of these things which are really hard to make different generally and consistently, since one would have to explicitly go against the standard evaluation sequence. I would reconsider the design of whatever you try to achieve with this. While I will be the first to suggest workarounds which change system's behavior in many cases, I also think that admitting and accepting certain limitations of the system can sometimes be more productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems disgusting, but here it goes

```
h /: Plus[x_h, l_List] :=
 withPlusListability[True][

  blabla; 0
  ]

withPlusListability[bool_: True | False] := Function[code,
   Internal`InheritedBlock[{Plus},
    Unprotect[Plus];
    If[bool, SetAttributes, ClearAttributes][Plus, Listable];
    code
    ], HoldFirst];

withH = withPlusListability[False];
```

So

```
withH[
  Print[h[3] + {4, 5}];
  Print[h[3] + 7];
 ];
```

prints

```
(*
0
7+h[3]
*)
```

While you evaluate code iniside `withPlusListability[True|False]`, it takes care that `Plus` has|doesn't have the `Listable` attribute, without changing it globally. `h`'s definition will only have a chance of matching with an unlistable `Plus`.

`Plus` is one of those symbols that are so special you really try not to mess with. As @Mr.Wizard warned, this will likely break for packed arrays, because it probably has been optimized to cut some corners.

Comment: @MrWizard, surprisingly, `h[3] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10];` works. Could you try it in v7?

Comment: Cool, didn't know about [Internal`InheritedBlock](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5686710)

Comment: Rojo: yes, it works.  I need to take a closer look at this.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to Rolf Mertig's comment I believe `$Pre` *does* work.

First define your function:

```
h /: myPlus[_h, _List] := 0
myPlus[other__] := +other
```

*Then* set `$Pre`:

```
$Pre = Function[x, Unevaluated@x /. Plus -> myPlus, HoldAllComplete];
```

Test:

```
h[1] + {4, 5, 6}
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

```
z[1] + {4, 5, 6}
```

> ```
> {4 + z[1], 5 + z[1], 6 + z[1]}
> ```

Comment: @RolfMertig is [pessimistic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19022/109) (comments) these days

Comment: `+other`!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! HAAAAAAAAAAA +1

Comment: You make it look so easy, thanks!

Comment: @Rojo I'm afraid I don't understand your outburst.  Unintentional humor?  Does "plus other" mean something in contemporary parlance?

Comment: @ssch Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: Yeye, act cool, as if `+something` is everyday notation to you, terseness master

Comment: @ssch I just realized I left out the huge limitation of this method: it only works on user input.  I didn't intend this to be a complete answer but rather a response to Rolf's comment.  My apologies if I made you think this was more than it is.

Comment: @Rojo ah, *that*!  I've been using that (in answers) for a while now so I didn't expect a sudden exclamation over it.  At first I didn't use it as I figured it would be controversial but now I don't really care about controversy. :^)  Later I'll find one of my earliest StackExchange uses of that form.  I also use `1##` as a shorthand for multiplication BTW.

Comment: @Rojo after a bit of searching I think perhaps the first time I used it here was [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5038/121).  I believe there are also posts in which I used `+##` but the search engine is fighting me.  More recently I used it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18586/121).  I've been using it much longer than this privately.